# How to update app without uninstalling old version form playstore?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, reinstall

Suppose in the PlayStore which is my version code 2 and version 5.0, Now I have created a new version which is version code 21 and version 5.1 Now I want to update Normally without updating it in the PlayStore. When I install the latest version it's showing app not installed.
How to update app without uninstalling old version.
I build sign apk same Keystore.

Comment: "I want to update Normally without updating it in the PlayStore" What does this mean? Update the version on your specific device? What's "normally"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.